# Can the additive inverse of a vector be itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, vector-spaces

I was going to prove that the Edge space (2^E) of a graph G(V,E) is a vector space over the binary field when I stumbled upon this question.

The addition was defined as the symmetric difference of the two sets which we are going to add.

And scalar multiplication is null if the scaler is 0, and the set itself, if the scaler is 1.

When I was about to prove theth axiom regarding the additive inverse I realized the additive inverse of some set in the Edge space is non other than the set itself. Am I doing this correctly? Feel free to edit LaTex as I'm typing with my phone. Thnx

Comment: In the field $\Bbb F_2$ of two elements, $-1=1$ so in a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$, $-v=v$.

Comment: Why does -1=1 in the binary field? Please explain.

Comment: Because $1+1 = 0$, which means that $1$ fulfills the _definition_ of $-1$.

Comment: Ohh... thamk you.. so the answer to my question is yes?

Comment: $0+0=0$, so $0=-0$ in **any** vector space (or more generallly, in any group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In order to make this question answered) Yes, in a vector space $V$ over the 2-element field, $-v=v$ for each $v\in V$.